# Sound Changes From Proto Bengali to Bengali

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, indian-languages

What are the sound changes that occur from Proto Bengali to Bengali? In which order did they  occur historically? 
Ex.
PB Būdhā became B Buro
PB Karisi became B koriš 
PB dahī became B doi

Comment: This question is likely too broad, if books could be filled with it, and thus reference to such a book would be enough of an answer. Unless you are aiming for imprecission.

Comment: What do you mean by Proto-Bengali? Perhaps the Middle Indo-Aryan Prakrit of Magadha (*Ardhamāgadhī*)? Or the common ancestor to Bengali and Assami languages?